# Modeling background noise with a half normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, model, measurement, noise

I'm working with radiation measurement data and have background noise data with $(\mu, \sigma)$ < 1  and all background measurement values >= 0. If I wanted to approximate/model this noise, would a half normal distribution make sense? If no, what is the best way to model/approximate noise that only takes on positive values and has a mean close to zero?

Comment: Have you considered analyzing the distribution of the noise to find out?  That usually is more realistic (and defensible) than just making stuff up (even when you're an expert).  Another approach is to analyze the implications of a physical model.  For instance, a major component of that noise is probably counting variation, which will have a nearly Poisson distribution before it is converted to radiation units.

Comment: I agree that it is more defensible but I was hoping to find a generalized model to avoid taking background measurements. I've analyzed my experimental background measurement distribution insofar as calculating the mean and variance which agree with that of a Poisson distribution. Would a zero-truncated Poisson be appropriate?

Comment: In my experience, to model the raw counts within a narrow spectral window it can be effective to use an untruncated Poisson distribution (to reflect the counting variability) whose rate is given by an underlying distribution that models short-term temporal variations in background and electronic noise in the instrument.  That underlying distribution tends to look square-root Normal or Lognormal (with fairly low coefficient of variation).  Reviewing the distribution of the data is quick and easy, so it behooves one not to settle just for estimating the mean and variance.

Comment: So the counts measured by the device is modeled by an untruncated Poisson distribution but the rate of counts emitted by the isotope is modeled by a log-normal or square root normal distribution? In terms of reviewing the distribution, what else can one do aside from mean and variance estimation (any source recommendation)? Thank you for the help!

Comment: With enough data you can attempt to characterize the distributional shape.  Understanding the measurement system in detail helps narrow the possibilities.